# Can I zoom in/out an asymmetric polygon drawn on UIMapView dynamically?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, mkmapview

I am trying to first draw a asymmetric polygon on the UIMapView using the MKPolygon as an overlay to it dynamically. After that, the end user should be able to zoom in/out that particular area only while the rest of the map area is kept with no effects.

Simply from an end user perspective, the person should be able to draw some area using his finger on the map view and then zoom that particular area ONLY while the other areas kept not affected by the zoom operation.

Comment: Is this even possible with MKPolygon and UIMapView ?

Comment: This certainly isn't possible using built in functions... I'd suggest a solution comprising of two map views, using the polygon as some sort of mask on a map view which can be zoomed overlayed over the background map view which doesn't zoom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no built in methods to do this.
Furthermore, official documentation is stating:

> You use this class as-is to display map information and to manipulate the map contents from your application. You can center the map on a given coordinate, specify the size of the area you want to display, and annotate the map with custom information.

So, to do what you are trying to achieve, you need to use two `MKMapView`, one over the other.

#### Project link

I made a simple project to show you the functionality, you can find it here: https://github.com/leonardfactory/mapview-polygon-mask

#### Screenshot

Here you can see the inner mapView displaying a zoomed map in a random polygon.
[image: iPhone screenshot with two MKMapView]

#### Explanation

Start adding two MKMapView, either programmatically or with storyboards.
After this, you can mask the topmost `MKMapView` with a `CAShapeLayer`, which path has been set using points from the `MKPolygon`.

`MKPolygon` however only stores `MKMapPoint`, so we need to transform these in CGPoint. What can we do?

An useful method to do this is provided by `MKMapView` itself, `convertCoordinate:toPointInView:`, that translates CLLocationCoordinate2D points into normal CGPoint, for example we can write a method like this:

```
/**
 *  Convert between MKMapPoint and CGPoint, to be used as masking path point.
 *
 *  @param point The MKMapPoint to be converted
 *
 *  @return The CGPoint, converted in UIView coords from MKMapPoint provided
 */
- (CGPoint) convertPointToMapView:(MKMapPoint) point
{
    return [self.mainMapView convertCoordinate:MKCoordinateForMapPoint(point) toPointToView:self.mainMapView];
}
```

Given a polygon so, you need only to create a CAShapeLayer path, using this helper method, and apply it as a mask to the other `MKMapView`, like this:

```
// Create a CAShapeLayer to hold masking path
CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
CGMutablePathRef mask   = CGPathCreateMutable();

// First point...
CGPoint firstPoint      = [self convertPointToMapView:polygon.points[0]];
CGPathMoveToPoint(mask, NULL, firstPoint.x, firstPoint.y);

// Then with some simple CG functions we can draw all the mask
for(NSUInteger i = 0; i < polygon.pointCount - 1; i++)
{
    CGPoint nextPoint   = [self convertPointToMapView:polygon.points[i+1]];
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(mask, NULL, nextPoint.x, nextPoint.y);
}

// Close path
CGPathCloseSubpath(mask);

maskLayer.path  = mask;
CGPathRelease(mask);

// Mask the second MKMapView
self.backgroundMapView.layer.mask           = maskLayer;
```

Some things to note:

- `polygon` is a MKPolygon. If you need to draw one from taps, you can use the MKMapView  method [convertPoint:toCoordinateInView:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MKMapView/convertPoint:toCoordinateFromView:),  which does the exact opposite of the method `converCoordinate:toPointInView` I used before.
- `polygon.points` is a C array of `MKMapPoint` (so its type is `MKMapPoint *`)

Comment: Thanks for the detail answer. Yes, I think it's impossible to implement this using only native methods. I am currently implementing my own one for this, I will share that once it gets complete. I think you well deserve a 50 points -:)